# Serialized JSON request results in "Bad Request" error

Tags: c#, json.net, httpwebrequest

I'm using Newtonsoft to try and serialize some JSON to do a HttpWebRequest POST

I keep getting a response saying 'Bad Request'

I'm assuming my JSON is badly formed.  Below is my code:

```
Account account = new Account();
account.Name = "TESTACCOUNT";

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://app01.nutshell.com/api/v1/json");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var tw = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
{

    serializer.Serialize(tw,
                 new
                 {
                   method = "newAccount",
                   @params = account                                      
                  });
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: A web server could return Bad Request for any number of reasons, not just malformed JSON: you could be sending the wrong parameters or omitting required parameters; you might have the wrong content type; you might be missing one or more headers the server is expecting; you could be sending to the wrong endpoint; you might not be writing your JSON to the request stream, or the server could have a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just the JSON:

```
{
    "method": "newAccount",
    "@params": "account"
}
```

http://pro.jsonlint.com/